# Change the behaviour of Enter key in iMessage

Tags: messages

I keep sending iMessages from my mac before I have finished typing them by accidentally hitting the return key.  Is there a way to change the behaviour to send on Cmd-Enter instead?

Comment: I don't think there's a way of changing this behavior, but if you want to insert a line break in your message, you can use `control`+`Enter` or `alt (option)`+`Enter`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I am aware that you can enter a new line with Alt-Enter, I'm just clumsy (UK layout has large enter key very close to backspace) and don't like that it sends so easily.

Comment: What is the equivalent in the iPad version?  I can't find a send key at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To override the default Enter behaviour I used the instructions posted in the question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/236255/135255

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to change behavior of Cmd-Enter Key you can use ALT + Enter/Return keys to create a New Line/paragraph in a text chat.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> creates a new line for Spanish layouts.