# How to make [return] behave as a [return] within Messages, Skype…

Tags: messages, shortcut

I am using `Messages` on both Macs & iPhones and I am typing a lot of E-mails.
Within all these environment I am used to the normal behaviour of the <kbd>return</kbd> key.

Within `Messages` this key doesn't behave as a return key thus causing me to prematurely send truncated messages.

I found this very similar question: [How to insert new line on return key press in iMessage on Mac OSX](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/198055/22003) and I already knew the workarounds proposed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>. But these workarounds didn't answer the original question. Moreover I already use them but this still leave me with an
**unacceptable error rate**.

From my point of vue, the <kbd>return</kbd> should never be associated with a "function" within an environment where you
are at typing text. This is a **huge ergonomic design error**.

I tried to override the actual shortcut mapping with:

```
defaults write com.apple.iChat NSUserKeyEquivalents '{ "                            
" = "insertNewline:" ; }
```

Which is a silent failure.

I suspect that the syntax of the function might be wrong, but `Messages` doesn't write any error about this.

Is there a documentation about the exact syntax of internal `Messages` functions which can be called from a shortcut?

Is there any other correct way to make the <kbd>return</kbd> behave as a plain <kbd>return</kbd>?

Comment: Any tweak may be dependant on you having both Return & Enter keys on your keyboard [not that I have an answer, just that laptops tend to only have one general purpose Ret/Enter, whereas desktops have both]

Comment: I have many keyboards on which I am working, some of them do have an `enter` key others don't (Mac Book Pro). Anyway, the key I have problem with is the key which is basically designed to enter a return many times per minute and is purposefully one of the larger of any keyboard. •••• I want my return :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Install Karabiner

Which can be found there: [Karabiner: a keyboard customizer for OS X](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en)

### Make a `private.xml`

Read the `Karabiner` documentation on the topic: [private.xml Reference Manual](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/xml.html.en)

Create the `${HOME}/Library/Application Support/Karabiner/private.xml`
with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>MESSAGES</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.iChat</equal>
    <equal>com.skype.skype</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>Messages return modification</name>
    <appendix>Change Return to Newline</appendix>
    <appendix>Change Newline to Return</appendix>
    <identifier>swap Return and Newline</identifier>
    <only>MESSAGES</only>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L, KeyCode::RETURN</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::RETURN, KeyCode::RETURN, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Depending upon your taste, use `vi`, `emacs` or `TextEdit`
(but of course not `Word`).

### Load your `private.xml`

Tell `Karabiner` you will use a custom setting:
[image: Use prepared settings]

and load it:
[image: Apply prepared settings]

### Test it

Start `Messages` or `Skype` and check that you can type <kbd>return</kbd> within any message and send a message with <kbd>command ⌘</kbd><kbd>return</kbd>.

Answer (score 7):

Create a file (on a standard install, the directory `KeyBindings` doesn't exist):

```
mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings
```

containing the following 2 remappings:

```
$ cat >~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict <<end_of_file
/* my keybindings */
{
        "\U000d" = ("insertLineBreak:") ;
        "@\U000d" = ("insertNewline:") ;
}
end_of_file
```

`@` means <kbd>cmd</kbd> in this dictionary,
`\U000d` means Unicode of the standard return (== `0x0d`).

Restart `Messages` and from now on,

- <kbd>return</kbd> will put a **real** <kbd>return</kbd>,
- <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> will **send the message**.

---

### Drawback

This solution is applied to any application using `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict`.

### Advantage

This solution is applied to any application which does a non *natural* use
of the return in a text area.
Most notably I now have a `Skype` with which I don't send any more prematurely truncated messages.

Comment: Hm, but is it a problem really, especially with Skype? it uses the standard keyboard behavior, alike other messengers do, so it's quick to get used to default behavior. I'm almost not using a mouse/touchpad, only keyboard combinations, and the chance of sending truncated messages almost absent.

Comment: It was regularly a problem because I am fast at typing and the return is a regular one I use. •••• This nightmare is now finished :).

Comment: Thank you so much for this, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Blessing on you and your house for 7 generations.  Is there a way to make it specific to a given application?

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford: have a look at this other answer (down here) which I am now using since 2 years: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/247214/22003 .

Comment: If I run into conflicts with other apps I'll look at Karabiner.  Installing a program that acts as a service to fix one keymapping is taking splinters to the emergency room.

Answer (score 6):

In Messages the keyboard combination to insert "new line" is:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>↩︎ Return</kbd>

It will not send the message, but will insert return carriage sign (a new line).

I'm using this all the time, when writing SMS/iMessages from MacBook... but yes, not really comfortable, as way too much of accidents when you are sending the truncated messages.

In most of Applications alike Skype and other Messengers insert of new line works on next keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>↩︎ Return</kbd>
- <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> + <kbd>↩︎ Return</kbd>

I do not recommend to override these shortcuts, as it's common-knowledge and standard behavior when working with Messages and Messengers.

In text processors, code editors and email editors have different behavior, as you see the big text area, and <kbd>↩︎ Return</kbd> acts as a "new line" action. Modifiers alike <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>, <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> might work as additional functionality to insert "soft" new line, to insert new page, line break delimiter, etc.

---

You might want to use [**BetterTouchTool**](http://www.boastr.de/), which is was a free utility which can disable keyboard shortcuts (and has many other uses). The list of your actions to disable/enable the shortcut could be next:

1. Install *BetterTouchTool*
2. Click on the `BetterTouchTool` menubar item and choose `Preferences`
3. Click on `Keyboard`
4. Click the plus sign at the bottom of the `Select Application:` pane
5. Choose `Messages` (in `/Applications` folder)
6. Click `+ Add New Shortcut`
7. Click `Keyboard Shortcut`, hit <kbd>return</kbd>
8. Click `Trigger Other Keyboard Shortcut`, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>
9. Leave `Trigger Predefined Action:` to `No Action` (which is the default)
10. repeat steps 7,8 & 9 to remap <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>

Which should lead to such a screen:
[image: Better Touch return remapping]

Answer (score 2):

Karabiner has changed, need json file now:
paste below into a text file, rename to messages.json and then copy into:
~/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications/
then add the two rules via the app

{"title":"Mac Messages return-key modify","rules":[{"description":"Use Return as New Line","manipulators":[{"type":"basic","from":{"key_code":"return_or_enter"},"to":[{"key_code":"return_or_enter","modifiers":["control"]}],"conditions":[{"type":"frontmost_application_if","bundle_identifiers":["^com\.apple\.iChat$"]}]}]},{"description":"Use Control Return as Send","manipulators":[{"type":"basic","from":{"key_code":"return_or_enter","modifiers":{"mandatory":["control"]}},"to":[{"key_code":"return_or_enter"}],"conditions":[{"type":"frontmost_application_if","bundle_identifiers":["^com\.apple\.iChat$"]}]}]}]}

Comment: It's the right idea, but I had to make modifications:

1. I'm not sure what Controls are doing here: this was probably for remapped modifiers. By default, we should be talking about Cmd modifiers.
2. The bundle identifier for Messages changed to `com.apple.MobileSMS`
3. With default Cmd modifiers, only Enter has to be remapped. Cmd+Enter works out of the box.

Comment: This is the rule I ended up with:
```
   {"description": "Use Return as New Line (*app-specific*)",
      "manipulators": [{
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {"key_code": "return_or_enter"},
          "to": [{"key_code": "return_or_enter",
          "modifiers": ["shift"]
          }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "frontmost_application_if",
              "bundle_identifiers": [
                "^com\\.apple\\.MobileSMS$"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```